# Find Avg after total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query

```
SELECT language, COUNT(language) AS countx, sum(COUNT(language)) OVER() AS totalcount
FROM table1
where Language is not null
GROUP BY Language
```

The result

```
language    countx  totalcount
English     1672    1693
Spanish       21    1693
```

Not sure how do I get AVG from countx/totalcount for each group so 1672/1693 and 21/1693.
Thank you.

Comment: That's not an average (AVG)

Comment: Note that if you have `where Language is not null` then `COUNT(language)` can be shortened to `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` because it only counts non-null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just divide:

```
SELECT language, COUNT(language) AS countx,
       sum(COUNT(language)) OVER () AS totalcount,
       COUNT(language) * 1.0 / sum(COUNT(language)) OVER()
FROM table1
WHERE Language is not null
GROUP BY Language ;
```

Some databases do integer division, which explains the `* 1.0`.